# Select an exact element and not its children

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a menu like this;

```
<ul>
 <li><a>1</a></li> 
 <li><a>2</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a>3</a></li>
   <li><a>4</a></li>
   <li><a>5</a></li>
   <li><a>6</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a>7</a></li>
     <li><a>8</a></li>
     <li><a>9</a></li>
    </ul> 
   </li>
  </ul>
  <li><a>10</li>
</ul>
```

If i want to make an selection on the 2nd level with jQuery.

```
$('ul li ul li') { action() }
```

But when i do this, this action will also be adopted by it's children, (ul li ul li ul li) i don't want that to happen.

I just want to select (ul li ul li).

With jQuery, how do i make it work?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to solve this is to give the outer `<ul>` a CSS class identifier or id. Then use the direct descendents selector

```
$('ul.className > li > ul > li') // CSS class className
```

or

```
$('#id > li > ul > li') // id id
```

Comment: I understand, but with an dynamic menu and in my case this isn't an option.

Comment: @molletje - You can still use this technique with a dynamic menu. Just make sure you are setting the class name (or ID) when you create the portion of the menu you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul > li > ul > li').action()
```

But you'll need to anchor the top-level `ul` somehow... with an ID, for example.

```
$('#menu > li > ul > li').action()
```

Comment: Okey, i my case it's #mainmenu ul li ul li

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a click handler that applies only to the element itself and not the elements contained in it?  I'd suggest using classes and adding a click handler to the subelements that prevents the event from bubbling up using [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).  The latter is needed because when you click on the inner element the event will also be fired on its parent.  If you really only want the handler to be invoked when you click on the element itself and none of its children, then you need to stop the event from bubbling up.

```
$('ul.secondlevel li').click( function() {
     // do something
} );

$('ui.thirdlevel li').click( function(e) {
       // do something else
       e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I have this
$('#mainmenu ul li ul li').mouseover() { action 1 }
and
$('#mainmenu ul li ul li ul li').mouseover() { action 2 }

both have another action in it, but with the second it fires both actions, the first selector works fine and won't start the second action

Comment: @molletje - that's a bit different because with mouseover the event will happen on the parent before the child (since you enter the parent before the child).  I'm not sure what I would do in that case -- I think you'd essentially need to delay the action in the parent and then check if propagation on the event has been stopped before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

> But when i do this, this action will
>   also be adopted by it's children, (ul
>   li ul li ul li) i don't want that to
>   happen.

Use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector to target a specific li:

```
$('#mainmenu li ul li').eq(5)............
```

Or its variation:

```
$('#mainmenu li ul li:eq(5)')............
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to select the `li`s containing 3, 4, 5 and 6?
If so, give their parent (second level) `ul`s an id and use the direct descendent selector with it:

```
$('ul#second_level_ul > li')
```

Comment: or just give the elements that you want to select a unique class